# Ruby on Rails:Access data from other table's column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

The 1st code below works

```
foos_set = Foo.where(foo_number: number)
foo = foos_set.first
if foo.project.status == "Ongoing"
#do sth
end
```

Where foo is a table,each of foo have a column called project,which link to a project table.and status is one column of table project.

Now I wan to do something similar,try check foo->its related project->status of the project

```
@foos = Foo.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@foos) do |foo, marker|
if foo.project.status == "Ongoing"
#do sth
else
#do sth 
end
```

It says that foo.project returns nil,thus I can't check foo.project.status .what is my problem?Do I miss some setting in model or controllers? 
I have put the working code into second controller,it produces error also.So it's some configure error.

Comment: If `foo.project` is nil, then there's no related record. So, why is that? Have you not associated a project with every `foo`, or do you have broken foreign keys?

Comment: @jefflunt this code worked once in other controller,which is not done by me.does it mean the foreign keys works  fine?

Comment: @Noon any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jefflunt said in his comment, you probably have a few `foo`s that aren't associated to a `project`, which you may want to attend to. To find any `foo`s that aren't attached to a project, you can use the following in your rails console:

```
Foo.where(project: nil)
```

If having a few `foo`s not associated to a `project` is something that you're ok with, or is expected, then you can do a few things to get around having a `nil` `project` associated to a `foo`.

```
if foo.project.present? && foo.project.status == "Ongoing"
```

This line checks to see if `foo` has a `project` attached to it, and if so, makes sure that the `project`'s status is "Ongoing". Better yet:

```
if foo.project.try(:status) == "Ongoing"
```

The `try` method returns `nil`, rather than throwing an error, if that particular `foo` does not have a `project`.